# Numpy covariance with weights?

Tags: python, numpy

When calculating the covariance in numpy, I have arrays with the data points, but I also have another array saying how many times each data point should be repeated. Is there a way to pass this array of weights to get the covariance directly, rather than manually copying each data point a certain number of times?

Comment: Welcome! Could you show (a sample of) your data, and what you have tried to solve the problem, or some research you may have done? That way we can help you better.